# Unwanted scrolling with an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-sites

I embedded a JSnes embed page I had made (found here: https://chilibowlflash.netlify.app/example/megaman2.html)  to a google site.

However, when I scroll down the whole page goes down with and not just the game inside the iframe. I don't want this. And instead want the game inside the iframe to go down, not the page inside the iframe or the actual google site . Any help? Or can't understand what I'm saying? I'm all ears!

Comment: That is because the embedded site is not active and the the pointer is scrolled outside the iframe.

Comment: @iamabdm any way to fix this?

Comment: I think this can be fixed if the user do not click outside the iframe and scroll, as it will deactivate the iframe. And to make people not click outside the iframe, you can set the iframe width to 100% or put the iframe at the bottom of the page and make it bigger in size and 100% width , so users ,if unusually clicks, they will click inside the iframe only.